# How to pass a value from HTML to Javascript and back to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

i have an mvc project that loads photo galleries from different folders. Pretty simple.

I have this function in my chtml View:

```
@foreach (var dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Customers/A")))
                    {enter code here
                        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
                        <li><a href="#">@dir.Name</a></li>
                    }
```

Which loads all the folders that are placed in A in my navbar.
Now, what i what to do is to load the photos and show them according to my folder pick. So i created the following function:

```
 @foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Customers/A/A"), "*.jpg"))
                {
                    var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);
                    <div class="col-md-3 batas">
                        <a href="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Images/Customers/A/Temp/{0}", img.Name))"><img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Images/Customers/A/Temp/{0}", img.Name))" data-lity class="img-thumbnail" /></a>
                    </div>
                }
```

Till now all works perfectly, means that my navbar contains all the folders that exist in A and it shows all the photos in Temp.
My question is, how can i and what is the best way to switch my gallery according to the users navbar folder pick?

Full HTML page can be found here: https://github.com/ohadki/ShmuliksProject/blob/master/ShmuliksProject/Views/Home/CustomerGallery.cshtml

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Use ajax to pass the value of the selected folder to a method that returns the associated images (as a partial view or `JsonResult`) and update the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

To Pass value from HTML (i.e. View) to Javascript

As, In MVC we can set values of HTML elements in View using associated Model, so we need to pass value from Model to Javascript

you can do it as follows:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var strValue = "@Model.YourObject"; //You set value here from your Model to any JavaScript object.
</script>
```

Now, If you need to send value from Javscript to Model you need to use ajax Get, Post or PUT methods to send data from javascript to Model and then to View.
Refer Link for [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i can bearly see how can i connect it all together..  
This value should be changed in every click at the navbar, and the value should be the content of the button (@dir.Name). Then i should place the updated value (after a button has been clicked) in the path instead of "Temp".
So, how exactly the script you wrote help me with updating this value?
Sorry for missunderstanding.